# how to solve mvc database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am Using Visual studio 2010 Ultimate edition registered version and want to develop ASP MVC 3.0 Project.
I need to include database in Asp_Data folder.I want to use .sdf version SQL server 2005,But when I use 
Data tab at--> Add New Item(By clicking at solution explorer)-->  It shows .mdf format only.
I am Using SQL Server 2005.
I installed SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.exe 4.0(Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 Setup)

Can anyone tell me how to get .sdf format of SQL Server 2005 in Data tab of Add new Item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install sql server compact 4.0 local database. Here's the link that will guide you to it. [Walkthrough: Working with SQL Server Compact in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg606540%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the SDF file using the *Server Explorer* -> *Connect to Database* in VS 2010.